# HTML Special characters: &dagger; and &Dagger in an DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, encoding

I have a dom document to which I would like to append some special characters.

What I am doing is first to detect the special character in a string with a regexp.
For that, I am transforming the utf-8 characters on html with

```
$string = "Test string 1,§,†,‡";
$string_html = htmlentities($string_html, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

This works fine and I am getting there:

```
"Test string 1,&sect;,&dagger;,&Dagger;"
```

Now, I would like to get the special characters only. I am using for that a regexp which is returning an array with:

```
[0] => '&sect';
[1] => '&dagger';
[2] => '&Dagger';
```

Now, I would like to append those special characters to my dom document, but in unicode. I was trying:

```
$string_utf8 = html_entity_decode($string_html);

$dom_output->createElement( 'string', utf8_encode($string_utf8));
```

The results are the next:

The § character is displayed as Â§, and the † and ‡ are staying as that.

Any idea why?

Comment: PHP's not my language, but the `utf8_encode` call looks like it ought to be unnecessary. Why do you think you need that call?

Comment: @Alohci, I need it because when doing $dom_output->createElement(), i need to have utf-8 encoded string becuse my dom document is utf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with `&sect;` is that it is at position `0xA7` in the unicode table. However, that particular character is encoded as the two-byte sequence `0xC2A7`. Your output is being rendered as ISO-8859-1 or similar encoding, resulting in this Â (`0xC2`) appearing before your intended character (since coincidentally it has the same last byte - it needn't, I frequently see é encoded as Ã© for example)

However the dagger and double-dagger are much further in the unicode table: `0x2020` and `0x2021` respectively. As such, there is no confusion when it comes to encoding them.

I *think* the problem may be caused by the PHP file itself being encoded in a single-byte character set, and it is this that is causing the issues with `0xA7`. Make sure your PHP file is encoded in the correct format, otherwise it will make incorrect assumptions about your strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Kolink. On which php file are you thinking? I don't understand you. Sorry

Comment: Well, the file that has `$string = "Test string...";` in it, I think.

Comment: In fact, I am getting this from a DOMDocument also.